# Menu in widget with yahoo style

Tags: menus

I would like to know the procedure to put my categories in the left menu on the widget in the same style of yahoo

I like this style:
ScreenShot-> http://broalliance.com.br/kafra/image-1ED5_4E270F69.jpg

what is the best option?

html and use a field to do manually?
how would the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your site source to see what classes do your category links have on them, then style these classes with CSS, like:

```
.category-5 a{
  background:transparent url(images/...) no-repeat left top;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: to be simpler and easier ,I only have four categories...
manually made ​​a html with these four categories as a list, and added as a widget through a field of html. So the question is, how can i do the traits under each category in the style of yahoo. See my menu: http://broalliance.com.br/kafra/image-AD92_4E27593E.jpg